# The Story of Jason & J____

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, story

One man was fighting another person. The victim was being punched and kicked and shoved, and the attacker had no intentions of stopping.

Then, two priests walked by. One of them noticed the fight and said to the other,

> *Transgressions! At the fight!*

The two priests ran to the two men and split them apart. The first priest who spoke continued,

> *Wrongdoer, violence (as well as everything thereof) is never the answer. Now thy days will end in the underworld.*

The attacker explained that the victim had better clothes than him, rode a better car than him, had a better life than him and would always laugh at him. The second priest then came forward and said,

> *Forever lawless/evil are the new grown hearts once they sin, twinged of high envy.*

The victim said the attacker might have envied, but not he; he was just teasing, though apologised nonetheless. The second priest who spoke continued,

> *So, strangers, end thy sins... or dwell in the ruined world.*

The two priests began to walk away, but the other two men asked for their names. The first one replied,

> My name is Jason.

The second one replied,

> My name is J____.

## What was the second priest's name?

---

I have not included a specific tag, for otherwise it may likely spoil the answer. After I have accepted an answer, I will include the tag.

**Hint:**

> Altogether, the first priest said 
>  *Transgressions! At the fight! Wrongdoer, violence (as well as everything thereof) is never the answer. Now thy days will end in the underworld.* 
>  
>  And the second priest said, 
>  *Forever lawless/evil are the new grown hearts once they sin, twinged of high envy. So, strangers, end thy sins... or dwell in the ruined world.* 
>  
>  Now that both their sayings are closer together, is it easier to notice something?

Comment: First thing that came to my mind was Jack though I believe that this is 100% wrong, lol (+1) :D

Comment: @KevinL yes, it is. The only thing correct in that name is the first letter, actually (and another letter, but that is in the wrong place). Just saying, this was an incredibly difficult puzzle to make :P

Comment: Indeed, I can see that this is another truly brilliant puzzle that you made (your puzzles before this were also great) :)

Comment: @KevinL Thank you! I really hope there is no mistake, though. It took me nearly two whole days to create this, and it was hard. Perhaps someone like **Deusovi** $\diamondsuit$ might figure this one out :D

Comment: Is the second name also five letters long? I ask becauseI think I know what the name should be, but I think that it doesn't quite add up. The four underlines seem to indicate four further letters after the J.

Comment: @MOehm yes, it is :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the second priest is called

> Jonas

on the (perhaps insufficient) basis that

> their two speeches are *almost* anagrams of one another.

But

> the first priest seems to have an extra AAATT

so perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree. Of course everything would be fixed if

> the second priest's name were an anagram not of JASON but of JASONAAATT

but that doesn't seem like it's possible.

Incidentally, MOehm's comments make me suspect that he may have figured out all of the above already but not thought it worth posting...

Comment: This seems pretty convincing with the one little "but". Maybe the priests were on their way to a card game and one of them was keeping an extra set of rot13[nprf shyy bs graf] up his sleeve :)

Comment: Yes, I found the mechanism, but drew a different conclusion: I thought that your "but" would form the new name, because the last line was accidentally copied in full when checking. I like your solution better. I didn't post, because I wanted to give the OP the opportunity to fix the post. The solution wasn't hard to find, because the same user posted a very similar and already solved question at the same time. Unfortunately, that one had an error, too.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, even though it might sound slightly off. It was supposed to have an extra AT (and not AAATT, although they do sound the same, slightly) but this was really hard to do for me, so sorry about that. The AT would show that all the letters in the name "Jason" are also *at* the other name. But apart from that, everything is correct. Well done! When would you like the tick? :P

Comment: This puzzle's idea is good, but I wouldn't have seen the answer without the similar puzzle about rebranded megacorps. It is hard to see the trick in the present, rather verbose format. Perhaps writing a dialogue where each pair of (short) phrases are angrams would work better. Putting in an additional AT doesn't work (but you knew that `:)`) and it sounds a bit like an excuse. By the way, you have introduced an extra missing C when copying the sentences to the hint.

Comment: @MOehm woops. I will fix that missing C. I will also consider your suggestion and perhaps use it for future puzzles. Thank you :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think I did see the one about rebranded megacorps, and I thought the answer would be "Jonas" -- or, I guess, "Janos" -- very early on though I hadn't explicitly noticed what was happening. So, aside from the missing letters, I don't think this is insolubly hard.

Comment: Okay, that's good. I didn't want it to be too hard, and I have never heard of the name Janos before. (I also do have heaps of riddles that have been unanswered, so Imma start giving hints out today.) I am glad this was answered. In fact... the answer will now be accepted!

Comment: Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @MOehm and yes, me saying that I intentionally put an additional AT was in fact a lie. I can now exhale the guilt flourishing within my soul, so that it ghosts over this comment and fades into the glare of my computer screen, irrevocably ceasing to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts (really just one)

> rot13(Jason) = Wnfba. Starting with "Wrongdoers" the next three sentences start with W then N then F. However the pattern stops there and there then is no B to be found anywhere in the priest's archaic speech...

Comment: That is not the answer, not is it related to the intended answer, hahah. That is just a pretty cool coincidence. $(+1)$ :P